# VirtualDocumentRoot Directive shows incorrect root directory

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am setting up virtual hosts on two domains.
Various sub domains have their own docroot.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName *.domain1.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/domain1/%1/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName *.domain2.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/domain2/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing

- http://www.domain2.com

should show

- /var/www/domain2/www/

but instead it looks for

- /var/www/domain1/www/

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `ServerAlias` option that udo mentioned to prevent one VirtualHost from catching everything. Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias *.domain1.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/domain1/%1/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAlias *.domain2.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/domain2/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias *.domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAlias *.domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2/
</VirtualHost>
```